# Regex to strip all tags in a text if it is surrounded by $$

Tags: php, regex

I need regex to strip all tags inside text if it lies between two consecutive $$. Two consecutive $$ forms a block.

For example:- The following text

```
This is <outtag>just</outtag> a test from $$outside and
<intag>from</intag> $$ inside and again <outtag>I am </outtag>inside out $$so I have
<intag>to go <\intag>in$$ go outside.
```

The `intag` must must be removed because it lies inside a block formed by two consecutive $$. I am trying to match it  with regex

```
(\$\$.*?)<(.+?)>(.*?)<\/\2>.*?\$\$
```

but I don't know how to repeat the tags that occur inside $$'s and also I don't know how to make blocks of two consecutive $$.

@nauriel I have a [mathjax](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php) code that is processed by [markdown](https://github.com/michelf/php-markdown) puts tags inside it if there are two underscores or some other markdown character.

And yes, I always have an even number of $$.

@sln just tags `<intag></intag>`, not the whole content of tag.

Comment: Are you sure you always have a pair of $$ ?

Comment: The simplest way would be to do it in two steps using `preg_replace_callback()`.

Comment: Just match `(?s)\$\$(.*?)$\$` then in a callback, strip the tags. Also, does the entire `<intag>from</intag>` need to be removed, or just `<intag>`from`</intag>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simple and straighforward:

```
$input = 'This is <outtag>just</outtag> a test from $$outside and
<intag>from</intag> $$ inside and again <outtag>I am </outtag>inside out $$so I have
<intag>to go </intag>in$$ go outside.';

$output = preg_replace_callback('/\$\$.*?\$\$/s', function($m) {
    return preg_replace('/<(.+?)>(.*?)<\/\1>/s', '$2', $m[0]);
}, $input);

echo $output;
```